# how to represent hive data for mahout's recommendations?

Tags: hive, mahout

I am a new bee in hadoop - big data analysis. I am referring book-"mahout in action".

Here i saw a topic which explains how we can represent recommender's data from database. In the book they have shown programmatic approach of connecting MySQL with mahout.

my question is "Is it possible to connect hive with mahout like we connect MySQL? if yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are pretty completely different things -- you're talking about using a non-distributed recommender with MySQL, versus a Hadoop-based non-distributed recommender with the output of Hive on HDFS. If you're using recommenders, the simplest thing is to get your output as simple CSV data on HDFS and use that as input.

Comment: thanks owen. As of now i am trying out recommenders with CSVs only. For my information, I wanted to know that what are the other datastores those can be used with mahout other than MySQL?